# Returning Value of Last value in Linked List Recursively

Tags: c

```
int last(Node *head)    // complete this, must be recursive
{
    Node *ptr = head;
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr->next == NULL)
            return ptr->num;
        else
            last(ptr->next);
    }
}
```

I am trying to return the last value and I have a feeling the problem has to do with the way I am trying to return the value, but I'm not sure exactly how I should go about it.

Comment: `else last(ptr->next);`-> `else return last(ptr->next);`.

Comment: maybe reading the warnings could help in those situations

Comment: after changing to     return last(ptr->next); I get the error: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }

Comment: @garrett1027 that's normal. Look what happens if `head` is `NULL`. That should answer the question why you get the warning: _control reaches end of non-void function_

Answer (score 2):

```
int last(Node *current)
{  
    // degenerate case
    if ( current == NULL ) return 0;  //or pick another number if you want

    // last element found
    if ( current->next == NULL ) return current->num;

    // recursive
    return last( current->next );
}
```